# Generating pseudorandom nonrepeating integers from a 32-bit finite set

Tags: random, numbers, generator

I want to take the set of 4 billion positive integers and output them in a pseudorandom sequence, such that no number is repeated until all 4 billion have been outputted. I want this sequence to be repeatable and predictable for a given seed.
Is there a good algorithm for producing such a sequence, without resorting to putting the ordered sequence in memory then running a pseudorandom sorting operation over the entire thing? The randomness can be very weak if it makes things easier.
Thanks

Comment: Is `return i++` too weak? ;-)

Comment: You could use assylias tongue-in-cheek answer and then xor the output with a fixed value (the seed).

Comment: You should be able to use bitwise operators in a certain sequence to create a seemingly random pattern, but is really completely non-random.  I would expect some recursion would be involved too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Linear Congruential Generator with appropriate values for `a (= 214013)`, `c (= 2531011)`,`m (= 2^32)` to make it full period.

```
X(n+1) = (a*X(n) + c) mod m
```

This will produce *all* 2^32 values without replacement and repeat the same sequence after that.